# Elementos de lista se muestran al lado en lugar de abajo

Tags: html, css

Hice un slider. Como no sé usar js lo hice solo con html y css, y al usar flex para ubicar las imágenes al centro, se me ponen mis `li` al lado en lugar de abajo. Adjunto imagen y códigos.

> Sé que es un poco enroscado pero soy muy nuevo en esto y aun no aprendí nada de javascript. Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la facultad y trato de arreglármelas de manera un poco artesanal.

HTML:

```html
<!--CARRUSEL DE IMAGENES-->


<div class="container">
        <ul class="slider">
            <li id="slide1"> <img src="../assets/slider/slide1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li id="slide2"> <img src="../assets/slider/slide2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li id="slide3"> <img src="../assets/slider/slide3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li> <a href="#slide1">1</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#slide2">2</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#slide3">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.slider {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

ul.slider li {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
}

ul.slider li img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

ul.slider li:first-child {
    opacity: 1;
}

ul.slider li:target {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Así se ve por ahora. Necesitaría que esos 1,2,3 queden debajo de las imágenes en lugar de al costado.
[image]

Comment: ¿Esta vez estás omitiendo Bootstrap? Por cierto, revisá qué se editó en tu pregunta para que tenga un mejor formato, para que así puedas redactar preguntas de mayor calidad.

Comment: Use bootsrap solo para una navbar que tengo mas arriba en la pagina, pero por que es lo unico que entiendo manejar un poco con bootsrap, esta no uso clases de bootsrap. Gracias por la correcion del formato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es bastante simple el error, lo que sucede es que cuando pones `display: flex` css da a ese elemento una propiedad de dirección por defecto que es `flex-direction` con un valor por defecto `row` (fila), esto organiza los elementos hijos en una fila de izquierda a derecha; en tu caso lo pones en el `container` haciendo que este distribuya tu `slider` y `menu` como lo dije anteriormente en una fila. Para lograr lo que necesitas debes sobre-escribir dicha propiedad especificando la dirección que quieres aplicar, en tu caso es `column` por lo que tienes que introducir `flex-direction: column` en tu código

te dejo un snippet aplicando esa propiedad para que puedas observar el resultado

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column; // justo aqui se hace la sobreescritura
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.slider {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

ul.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.slider li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ul.slider li:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul.slider li:target {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li id="slide1"> <img src="https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li id="slide2"> <img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png" alt=""></li>
    <li id="slide3"> <img src="https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/66f52e9bb4ff451ed48c01e2eb5d54e9.webp?image_crop_resized=1280x720" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li> <a href="#slide1">1</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#slide2">2</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#slide3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```